# Removing outermost braces

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to calculate the Kronecker product of several matrices in different orders. the

number of these matrices must be changeable.

```
sysdim = 5;(* number of matrices I want to multiply. this number must be changeable*)

id = IdentityMatrix[sysdim];

sp = (* it's a matrix. It can be anything. It's size is sysdim by sysdim*)

Do[Subscript[variable, i] = ReplacePart[KroneckerProduct[id, id, id, id, id], {i ->
sp}], {i, 1, sysdim}]
```

By this I can get all different Kronecker products corresponding to different orderings. However, I want to

change the number of these matrices as I wish. So, I thought the solution could be

something like this:

```
KroneckerProduct[Table[id,{i,1,sysdim}]]
```

The problem here is that the `Table`command returns:

```
{id, id, id, id, id}
```

which `KroneckerProduct`is not happy with. I need to get rid of the outermost braces to

get the `KroneckerProduct`to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs on `Apply`:

> Apply[f,expr] or f@@expr replaces the head of expr by f.

So you can use `Apply` (`@@`)  to replace the `Head` of `Table[...]` (which is `List`) with `KroneckerProduct`:

```
KroneckerProduct @@ Table[id, {sysdim}]
```

Comment: Since the index of the Table is not used in the table's expression you can use the more compact form:  KroneckerProduct @@ Table[id, {sysdim}]

Comment: Good point, thank you @BobHanlon -- edited the post with your suggestion.

Comment: @kguler. Thank you. When I use `{i, {sysdim}}`, Mathematica returns error but if I use `{i,1,sysdim}` or `{sysdim}` as Bob suggested everything is O.K.

Comment: @yashar, it took three edits to get from `{i, 1, sysdim}` to `{sysdim}` :) fixed now..